# Show two fields of data on an Access graph

Tags: ms-access, graph

I am creating a graph as an Access form, and I can't figure out how to show two fields of data on the same graph.  I have a table of data (well, a query really):

```
tran_type | avg_cycle_time | count_of_cycle_time
A         | 26             | 1
B         | 31.5           | 2
C         | 42.56          | 25
```

Right now I have a bar graph of `avg_cycle_time by tran_type` (so A, B, C across the horizontal axis and then three bars showing the 26, 31.5 and 42.56 values).

Ideally what I'd like to do is show the count of values within that bar, though I imagine that could be tricky, so I'd settle for a line graph or something to show the counts (for this situation, I think it's important that when the user sees an average, he/she also sees how many data points played into that average).

I know depending on the data this might mean having two scales on the vertical axis, but I'm not sure if that's a problem or if it's supported.  I feel like I've seen this type of thing done in Excel, and maybe Access graphs aren't as robust, but unfortunately the app is in Access, so hopefully there's a solution.  I can use VBA if need be.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around, this was actually easier than I was making it.  When setting up the graph using the wizard, drag both fields (in this case avg_cycle_time and count_of_cycle_time) to the vertical axis.  If a bar chart is selected, this will create two bars side by side for each tran_type.  What I learned though is you can right click on one set of bars (in Design mode) and select Chart Type, and that will alter the type for just that data series.  So I changed the second set of bars to a line.

If you then want to have a second set of axis values (say if one field was a number and the other was a percentage, or the values in each set are out of whack), you can right click on the series and select Format Data Series, and on the Axis tab choose Secondary axis.  You can also show the value of that series--on the Data Labels tab select to show values.  This got me what I was looking for in showing the number of data points for each bar (even though the actual value is associated with the line, it's still what I was hoping to represent).